# /StartupItem/ Error, How to resolved the issue?

Tags: macos, error, startup

I'm using Macbook Pro late 2011 and I'm getting this error in my startup.

I've already performed **Repair Disk Permission** in my **Utilities**; 
I've also upgraded from Lion to Mountain Lion (*10.8.3*) but non of the solutions repaired it. I don't want to install fresh Mountain Lion and re-install again, it would be a tedious solution. Any idea how can this be resolved?

Errors Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to reinstall VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can not start in normal mode you need to start up in

> [Safe mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1455)

.

Then you can reinstall or delete the problem applications.

While in Safe mode look in to the Console for more information on start up problems.